# How to change the values of a numberpicker depending on the value of another one

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to show a different set of values in a numberpicker if the value of the first numberpicker is "B" or "E"

I tried to create an if statement, but it crashes when selecting "E" or "B"

```
val chordPicker = findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.number_picker)
        val chordImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.chordImage)

        val chordValues = arrayOf("C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B")
        var chordValue = chordValues[0]

        chordPicker.displayedValues = chordValues
        chordPicker.minValue = 0
        chordPicker.maxValue = chordValues.size - 1

        val chordTypePicker = findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.number_picker2)
        chordTypePicker.displayedValues = chordTypeValues
        chordTypePicker.minValue = 0
        chordTypePicker.maxValue = chordValues.size - 1


        chordPicker.setOnValueChangedListener { picker, oldVal, newVal ->
            chordValue = chordValues[newVal]
            val newList: Array<String> = if (chordValue == "E" || chordValue == "B") {
                arrayOf("M", "m", "7", "m7", "dim", "maj7", "m6", "aug")
            } else {
                arrayOf("M", "m", "7", "m7", "dim", "maj7", "m6", "aug", "#", "#7")
            }
            chordTypeValues = newList
            chordTypePicker.minValue = 0
            chordTypePicker.maxValue = newList.size - 1
            chordTypePicker.displayedValues = newList
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update the values in the listener for `chordTypePicker`.

Here's how the code may look like:

```kotlin
    val numberPicker1: NumberPicker = findViewById(R.id.number_picker)
    val chordList = arrayOf("C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C")
    numberPicker1.displayedValues = chordList
    numberPicker1.minValue = 0
    numberPicker1.maxValue = chordList.size - 1

    val numberPicker2: NumberPicker = findViewById(R.id.number_picker2)

    numberPicker1.setOnValueChangedListener { picker, oldVal, newVal ->
        val newList: Array<String> = if (chordList[newVal] == "E" || chordList[newVal] == "B") {
            arrayOf("M", "m", "7", "m7", "dim", "maj7", "m6", "aug")
        } else {
            arrayOf("M", "m", "7", "m7", "dim", "maj7", "m6", "aug", "#", "#7")
        }
        numberPicker2.minValue = 0
        numberPicker2.maxValue = newList.size - 1
        numberPicker2.displayedValues = newList
    }
```

NOTE: you need to update the maxValue and minValue (it is optional because in both case the value is 0) before setting the value of second number picker.

Comment: OP tagged Kotlin and not Java. They might not be able to use this.

Comment: Hi, after adding this code (I translated the code to Kotlin), I get an error when trying to select "E" or "B", the exact error is this: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 26561
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=9

Comment: @Delirium1608 we need to set `numberPicker.minValue` and `numberPicker.maxValue` first.

Comment: @Delirium1608 check the updated answer. Note that I've set the max value as `listSize - 1`

Comment: Hi, this code does what I wanted, but it still crashes with the same error, in fact, the code does not crash for example, if the second numberpicker is set to one of the values of the middle, but keeps crashing when using the first or last values with the same error, I don't know if I used your code correctly, I will update the question so you can see the current one, thanks for the patience and help